# Pagination for Associations in view or edit of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

My model consists of Merchants which have many Offers.

If I now open in rails admin any merchant I see all of the offers of this merchant, which is good.
This can take some time, because a merchant can have thousands of offers.

How is it possible to solve this?
My first idea was to have a pagination for the offers, which are shown in the merchant detail page.
Also then I want to show some custom fields of the offer in the list.